# Sending the mail using mutt command

Tags: shell, mutt

I have a requirement where I need to send two files A and B . The file A's content should be displayed as in-line or body of the mail and file B as an attachment.

Is multiple attachment using mutt is possible?

The command

```
 echo "Hello everyone " | mutt -s 'My mail ' abc@gmail.com -a myFile.txt
```

is writing Hello everyone as body of the mail and myFile.txt as an attachment(inline).

Both of my files A and B are dynamically generated, so I cannot have an echo statement.

Comment: When you say "files A and B are dynamically generated" does that mean you never a real file on the disk anywhere?

Comment: those are generated by a shell script. The shell scripts calls some plsql procedure to generate report files(file A and B).

Answer (score 5):

It's actually very simple:

```
mutt -s 'My mail ' abc@gmail.com -a report1.txt < report2.txt
```

If you had two scripts to create the reports, you could use pipes (i.e. no files would be created on disk):

```
script2 | mutt -s 'My mail ' abc@gmail.com -a <(script1)
```

Comment: Just a question, when you pipe, don't you actually create a file? That's why stdin, stdout and stderr are called file descriptors

Comment: @miraunpajaro No, you don't. They are called file descriptors, because they refer to something that can be **used** as a file, which might or might not **be** an actual file. In this case when mutt tries to read the data, script2 generates them. While mutt is processing the data, script2 is paused.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat A | mutt -s 'My mail' abc@gmail.com -a B
```

If the shell script prints file A's content to standard output, like this:

```
script >A
```

then you can use `tee` to print both to the file A and into the pipe to mutt:

```
script | tee A | mutt -s 'My mail' abc@gmail.com -a B
```